# What is the time imaginary method?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, software, wick-rotation

I have to submit homework about the scheme which solves the time-independent Schrödinger equation and finds the ground state by the imaginary time method.

I know the substitution $-\mathrm{i}\tau\mapsto\tau$ and $\tau\to\infty$, but I don't know how to start it and finish it. I am going to use Python. Could you help me?

Comment: I guess this could be edited into a good question about physics. Please consider adding more detail about the method and making the question about how that method works conceptually. (That you are using Python is, by the way, irrelevant for the physics.)

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can propagate the Schrödinger equation to imaginary time. This means solving the following equation

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} | \Psi > = -H |\Psi> $$.

The initial state can always be expressed as a linear combination of eigenstates of $H$

$$ |\Psi(0)> = \sum_n c_n |n>$$

Solution to to imaginary time Schrödinger equation is given as

$$ |\Psi(t)> = \sum_n c_n exp(-t \epsilon_n) |n>,$$

which means that the lowest eigenvalue of H will eventually dominate, if it had originally even a small component $c_n$. For example, one can find the smallest eigenvalue and eigenvector of 2x2 matrix like this with octave

```
H = [ -2 1 ;
       1 2 ];
psi=[1;0];
realE = min(eig(H))
dt = 0.1;
while 1
    psi = psi - dt*H*psi;
    psi = psi / norm(psi);
    E = psi'*H*psi
    pause(0.1)
end
```

This prints

```
realE = -2.2361
E = -2.1379
E = -2.1960
E = -2.2199
E = -2.2295
E = -2.2334
E = -2.2350
E = -2.2356
E = -2.2359
E = -2.2360
E = -2.2360
E = -2.2361
E = -2.2361
E = -2.2361
E = -2.2361
```